# SSH authorized_keys and newline

Tags: ssh, debian, openssh, authorized-keys

I am trying to configure SSH with public-key authentication on Debian.
I can't seem to get it to work because auth.log keeps saying that can't read key type:...(key line)\n.

It keeps complaining about the newline and i can't remove it. I open the file, i delete the newline but it's added again.

Thank you in advance

Edit:I managed to remove the newline, but now i have the same error i had last night. I started with a 4096 RSA key but given this error i thought ssh did not accept 4096 bit keys (i know it is stupid but i had to try). Here is the error from auth.log:

```
Sep 11 08:36:18 fortknox sshd[5002]: error: buffer_get_string_ret: bad string length 813826338
Sep 11 08:36:18 fortknox sshd[5002]: error: key_from_blob: can't read key type
Sep 11 08:36:18 fortknox sshd[5002]: error: key_read: key_from_blob MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAvGOorkMkY7OX6iQrTWm+JeFxysPm02PRTcOMQlIrAkYSkCody07Y5+e7IPFXoRIHgzecpZ/KeA13T6qa7x5pRu65xAyvsnkvW5YFxVkv/JNvS3EBKpOE22dkO2xC5Dv7id/Aw3QtnzdwZhllczmOoSRbtPfJK4oxLNcy6lAqiN1XQLWl/2I7GglTawJCAsXpqXdXsJGFqnQkMPWkVo3LTlcZVgzH+ChURJTRutNJCeEm8d+FzGfTICCoPveOhlytJTAXtsDLKGgEoK2XoGfUH3OGRsBq0WssINXvopfhrfhTaBxKZ7kr3WLQSHHy6A/xxlTwA81wNuiXNBdGUGSaVwIDAQAB cryptosec@fortknox.sec failed
```

Comment: Could you add the relevant line from authorized_keys to your question? Feel free to munge the long hexidecimal part.

Comment: let's see some extracts from the command line that demonstrate what is going on

Comment: And the size of the public key file, it seems to be way too large: bad string length 813826338. This may indicate file or filesystem corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Use the original .pub file that was generated (or generate a new key pair) and then add it to authorized_keys this way:

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ssh-copy-id to localhost:

```
ssh-copy-id -i identity_file localhost
```